# Getting the last modified date of folders and files with Python and ftplib

Tags: python, date, ftp, ftplib

My simple code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

connect = FTP('pompompom')
connect.login("pompompom")

connect.retrlines('LIST')
```

This gets me a list of all the folders and files in my directory. I'm trying to have them sorted by the last modified date, the problem is that some of my output looks like this.

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 1035     1005         4096 Jan 17  2013 test
drwxr-xr-x    2 1035     1005         4096 Dec 31 22:21 test2
drwxr-xr-x    2 1035     1005         4096 Jan 05  2013 test3
```

So while most entries give me a year, month and day, some give me a month, day and hh:mm instead. How do I get the year for those? (And, if possible, the hh:mm for the others?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of year, you may consider it as current year. Subtract one in case the date is in future.

e.g.
Current date 14 Feb 2014.

Jan 17 - Year is 2014
Dec 31 - Consider year as 2014. Since, it is future date, subtract 1. Year becomes 2013.

Comment: This is unfortunately not the case - as you can see in the example above there is an entry from Dec 31 2013.

Comment: Today is Feb 2014. Dec 2014 is date in future. Hence, subtracting 1 and the year becomes 2013.